# Is there an influxdb ui API to import json model charts?

Tags: influxdb

I am using the influxdb UI to chart some data using influxql. I want to be able to deploy these charts out alongside the database. There is a way to export these charts to JSON models, and you can import these charts via the UI with the exported JSON.

Is there any way to import these JSON models via an API? I cannot find any mention of one in the docs.

Edit: the CLI seems to only support export, but not import: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/reference/cli/influx/dashboards/